# Pandas - assign column values to new columns names

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
player_id    scout_occ  round scout
812842         2        1     X
812842         4        1     Y
812842         1        1     Z
812842         1        2     X
812842         2        2     Y
812842         2        2     Z
```

And I need to transpose 'scout' values to columns, as well as using number of occurrences as value or these new columns, ending up with:

```
player_id     round  X  Y  Z
812842        1      2  4  1
812842        2      1  2  2
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['player_id', 'round'], columns='scout', values='scout_occ')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, thanks. how do I unstack columns, getting rid of scouts and keeping X, Y, Z as columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). For example:

```
df = df.pivot_table(values='scout_occ',index=['player_id','round'],columns='scout')
```

Then if you don't want to use column name(**scout**):

```
df.columns.name = None
```

Also, if you want to use **player_id** and **round** as a column not as an index:

```
df.reset_index()
```